# What are the benefits of having more than one command post in Horde 2.0?

Tags: gears-of-war-3

In each of the Horde maps you have the option of setting up a command post when you start the game in one of 4 possible positions, which is free to set up. After that you are able to buy a second command post in any of the other 3 available positions for $2000.

Usually, I try to pick the best location when setting up the first command post, and at the moment I can't see any advantages of setting up a second command post. Especially when that money could be spent upgrading barriers and turrets, and a second command post doesn't seem to have any immediate effect.

Am I missing something? Are there any benefits for having multiple command posts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From experience, a single command post is sufficient to occupy the money and man-power of two players.  Unless you want to spread out or, as [Tom-grochowicz](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/8239/tom-grochowicz) mentions in his answer, build a back-up base, there isn't a lot of gain to be had from building this in the early game.

However, if you are playing with more than two people then the additional defences unlocked by having a second command post can be used to compliment each other.  For example, you might want a turret per person, which you will need at least another command post for.

*When you haven't been playing Horde mode long*, there are certain unlocks for Horde 2.0 that a second command post can help with:
The **Infinite Ammo** mutator for Horde requires you to `Earn a Combat Engineer ribbon 100 times`. To earn this ribbon, you must work on five fortifications in a single round [[source](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/gears-of-war-3/Mutator_Unlock_Guide)].  A second (or more) command post will provide a new set of potentially cheap barriers to build and repair, which will enable you (and others) to get this medal faster.  This will also help to level up your fortifications faster.

*When you have been playing horde mode for a while*, you will have achieved some or all of the fortification levels and unlocks.  Many of these make fortifications cheaper to repair and maintain, which means you will find yourself with more money as you progress.  You may find that you simply have a cash excess that you would like to sink into more barriers and decoys.
For example, [with barriers](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/gears-of-war-3/Fortifications), repair becomes cheaper at each even level:

- Level 2 - Spike Barrier Repair Cost 8% Less - Level 1 Decoy Unlocked
- Level 4 - Razor Wire Repair Cost 8% Less - Level 1 Turret Unlocked.
- Level 6 - Electrified Barrier Repair Cost 8% Less  Level 8 - Laser
- Barrier Repair Cost 8% Less

Comment: +1 - hadn't even considered using an extra post to boost my fortification levels. Good suggestion!

Comment: It didn't occur to me either until today, whilst I was reading up on how to unlock the mutators :)

Answer (score 3):

A second command post is only useful if you need to relocate your base, or set up a fall-back position. Even if you buy a command post, units can still spawn it in, so it's not a matter of controlling all areas of the map.

If you really wanted to think outside of the box, you could set up barriers and decoys at other bases to slow down and distract your enemies, but the benefit behind that is questionable, since that's less money you could spend at your real base.

Answer (score 1):

if you buy all the command posts, you can upgrade them, until eventually you can activate them to automatically fire at enemies with power weapons, such as the Hammer of Dawn.

Certain levels are simple enough with 1 command post, but 2 of them next to each other will make your life a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

One tactic that I prefer is gaining a lot of money ASAP and then buying multiple command posts. Once I have those, I buy auto-turrets at each one and upgrade them.